# Getting photo information from camera intent

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am having a very difficult time with the camera intent and trying to get data about the photo that was just taken

I launch the camera like this

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
File output = new File(dir, "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
photoUri = Uri.fromFile(output);
startActivityForResult(camera, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

in my `onActivityResult` the intent is null so I cannot use anything there to get the Uri but doing this.

```
Bitmap photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),photoUri);
```

gets the photo just fine. What I want to do is get information about the photo `Latitude,Longitude,time taken etc` so I tried this

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.query(getContentResolver(),photoUri,null,null,null,null);
```

but the cursor is always returned as null so it obviously cannot find the uri. It seems that the image is not getting out into the MediaStore provider. How can I get the data from the photo just taken?

Comment: There is no requirement for the camera app to update the `MediaStore` on your behalf. Use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh so the `MediaStore` just needs to be updated with the changes and doing something like a device restart would achieve this just as a proof of concept since on a restart everything gets scanned again correct?

Comment: Everything should get scanned again on a reboot, though how quickly that will be done I can't say -- it'll depend in part on how much media you have, I imagine.